# Detecting black spots on image - Image Segmentation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to segment an image with Color-Based Segmentation Using K-Means Clustering. I already created 3 clusters, and the cluster number 3 is like this image:

[image: Cluster 3]

This cluster has 3 different colors. And I want to only display the black spots of this image. How can I do that?
The image is 500x500x3 uint8.

Comment: You could easily do something like this `imshow(~all(img == 0, 3)))`

Comment: Thank you, thats helps. And how can I count the number of black spots of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Those "holes" look like they are well defined with the RGB values all being set to 0.  To make things easy, convert the image to grayscale, then threshold the image so that any intensities less than 5 set the output to white.  I use a threshold of 5 instead to ensure that we capture object pixels in their entirety taking variations into account.

Once that's done, you can use the function [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) from the image processing toolbox (I'm assuming you have it as you're dealing with images) where the second output tells you how many distinct white objects there are.

Something like this could work:

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/buW8C.png');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
holes = im_gray < 5;
[~,count] = bwlabel(holes);
```

I read in the image directly from StackOverflow, convert the image to grayscale, then determine a binary mask where any intensity that is less than 5, set the output to white or `true`.  Once we have this image, we can use `bwlabel`'s second output to determine how many objects there are.

I get this:

```
>> count

count =

    78
```

As an illustration, if we show the image where the holes appear, I get this:

```
>> imshow(holes);
```

[image]

---

The amount of "holes" is a bit misleading though. If you specifically take a look at the bottom right of the image, there are some noisy pixels that don't belong to any of the "holes" so we should probably filter that out.  As such, a simple morphological opening filter with a suitable sized structure will help remove spurious noisy islands.  As such, use [`imopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) combined with [`strel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html) to define the structuring element (I'll choose a square) as well as a suitable size of the structuring element.  After, use the structuring element and filter the resulting image and you can use this image to count the number of objects.

Something like this:

```
%// Code the same as before
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/buW8C.png');
im_gray = rgb2gray(im);
holes = im_gray < 5;

%// Further processing
se = strel('square', 5);
holes_process = imopen(holes, se);

%// Back to where we started
[~,count] = bwlabel(holes_process);
```

We get the following count of objects:

```
>> count

count =

    62
```

This seems a bit more realistic.  I get this image now instead:

```
>> imshow(holes_process);
```

[image]